# Why can't I see, "New...angular component" in context menu?

Tags: angular, webstorm

Once I create an Angular project within WebStorm 2019.2.2, I am unable to right click on the app folder and find, "New...component" within the context menu.

I have tried to create the .angular-cli.json file manually and then add it to the project root folder.

Comment: it should be **New > Angular Schematic**, **Component** (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/angular.html#generate_angular_structures). What CLI and Node.js versions do you use? Why did you try creating .angular-cli.json file manually?

Comment: I tried to create it manually because the latest version created a file called angular.json and not the .angular-cli.json file.  I found this idea in one of my searches for a solution to my problem.  I don't remember what site it was on.  By this point I was scrambling for a solution.

Comment: Bam!  Thank you lena!  One final question...how do I give you the credit you so richly deserve?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Select File | New | Project from the main menu or click Create New Project on the Welcome screen. The Create New Project Dialog opens.

In the left-hand pane, choose Angular CLI.

In the right-hand pane:

Specify the path to the folder where the project-related files will be stored.

In the Node Interpreter field, specify the Node.js interpreter to use. Select a configured interpreter from the list or choose Add to configure a new one.

From the Angular CLI list, select npx --package @angular/cli ng.

Alternatively, for npm version 5.1 and earlier, install the @angular/cli package yourself by running npm install -g @angular/cli in the Terminal ⌥F12. When creating an application, select the folder where the @angular/cli package is stored.

Optionally, in the Additional parameters field, specify the extra [ng new options](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new) to pass to Angular CLI. Code completion is available in this field: as you start typing the name of an option or press ⌃Space, WebStorm shows you the available options and their description.

When you click Create, WebStorm generates an Angular-specific project with all the required configuration files and downloads all the newcessary dependencies.

Comment: Been there, done that Adnan.  That is a copy/paste of the instructions.